# Support for Resource Overview in Omniplan

Tags: pm-software, resource-planning

In [Omniplan 2.3.5](http://www.omnigroup.com/omniplan), Is there any way to create a Resource report similar to the report Microsoft Project offers?

This report should include:

- how many hours does a resource work
- when do they start
- when do they end and
- export this in report or chart

Alternatively, would it be possible to do by importing the project file to a different program? I tried using  Microsoft Project, but the data is not correctly transferred (I get wrong days and no resources).

Comment: Hi Strommer, welcome to PMSE. As this question stands, it's strongly likely that it'll be considered off topic. Check our [faq].

Answer (score 0):

See: http://downloads2.omnigroup.com/software/MacOSX/Manuals/OmniPlan-2-Manual.pdf

Search for the Resource View.

It will allow you to allocate the number of hours worked, start/end times, and can be exported as a PDF or Excel document.